# How to change dynamically the id on a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I want to save my data in a json, but with the id of the data generated from the value of a variable:

```
  updatePoints = (group, data) => {
    this.setState({group: data});
  }
```

In this case, the value of group is 'round_1'. I want that in my state, the object looks like:

```
{
round_1: {...data...}
}
```

but, of course, it is saving like:

```
{
group: {...data...}
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your object values like this

```
this.setState({[group]: data})
```

So:

```
updatePoints = (group, data) => {
    this.setState({[group]: data});
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing the following:

```
this.setState({ [group]: data });
```